# Extra capability to wordpress user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am trying to make editors(role editor) view users in wordpress. By default editor can not view users (list_user)

I searched different forums and found various codes but couldnot get desired result using any

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'can_edit_posts' );
```

I am not able to figure out how to use these (where to put and how)

thanks

Comment: I got this issue resolved using a plugin for wordpress that allows to modify user roles. Thanks a lot.

Comment: wordpress role editor plugin helped me https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor
will see its code sometime later and share here. Thanks